# Okhttp request fails when the request body contains %

Tags: java, spring-boot, okhttp

I am using okhttp client to make requests to twitter. When the request body(status param) contains % it getting failed.

below is the code I am using to make a request

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                  .build();
                MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "status=test % test&media_ids=1690251004548407296");
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                  .url("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json")
                  .method("POST", body)
                  .build();
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

When i remove the % from the status param it is getting successfull otherwise, I am getting 400 error.

But the same has been working with POSTMAN. I have copied the code from postman.
Also I tried unirest client, it is working without issues in unirest.

Comment: Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40669128/okhttp-unwanted-escaping-of-form-data